# Broken Image Link - Custom HTML module

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

I have created a default Custom HTML module, and put few thumbnail images and added hyperlinks. And when i see preview it show broken image link on few menus and some time it work perfectly. I checked both image urls from front-end.

Broken Image url: mysite.com/entertainment/images/geo_news.jpg

Working image url: mysite.com/images/geo_news.jpg

And my thumbnails are in /images/ directory

I just dont understand why on specific menu or browser it display broken link on few menu items? although it is working fine on other menus or on home page. I check backed and hyperlinks are fine. Even i cleared Joomla Cache but same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for response. I found the problem. Changed plugin order, and put System-SEF plugin before System-Cache. Broken image links are working now.

As i mentioned that all paths are correct, so after changing plugin order, issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "entertainment" added from url rewriting when a menu with this alias is clicked.So when your path url is relative,the alias is added. You have to put the entire link to your custom module's html at `<a>...</a>` element.

```
mysite.com/images/geo_news.jpg
```

and not

```
../images/geo_news.jpg
```

or something like that!

Hope i help you!

Answer (score 0):

This might help others as I was having similar issues. All I had to do was actually enable "System-SEF" plugin and "System-Cache"